# Magento2 Add custom html before totals on cart page

Tags: magento2, cart, magento2.2

How we can add custom HTML before order total in cart page with Knockout JS same as the screenshot below.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Create checkout_cart_index.xml at**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="fee" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/fee</item>
                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/checkout/cart/totals/fee</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>

                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**2. Now create fee.html at**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/cart/totals/fee.html

```
<!-- ko -->
<div>Here You can do your html</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

**3. Create fee.js at (Here You can create functions for html)**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/fee.js

```
define(
    [
        'Vendor_Module/js/view/checkout/summary/fee'
    ],
    function (Component) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            //Create function
        });
    }
);
```

I added custom total at this place you can prefer my module for more details: https://github.com/mageprince/magento2-extrafee

Answer (score 0):

You can add your custom html content in this file:

/app/code/design/your_package/your_theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/totals.phtml

```
<div id="cart-totals" class="cart-totals" data-bind="scope:'block-totals'">
    <div class="custom-html">Custom Html Before Totals</div>
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
            {
                "#cart-totals": {
                    "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>
                }
            }
    </script>
</div>
```

I hope it will work for you.

[image]

Comment: I am creating a module. I don't want to override phtml file. Please suggest me the other solution.